# NestJS : ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ClientService

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, dto

I am working with NestJSproject. I make an entity Client and a DTO for the "inscrit()" function

when I ran the project, I got the following:

```
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ClientService (?). Please make sure that the argument ClientRepository at index [0] is available in the ClientModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If ClientRepository is a provider, is it part of the current ClientModule?
- If ClientRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ClientModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ClientRepository */ ]
  })
```

this is the `client.service.ts`  file

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { ClientInscritDto } from './dto/client-inscrit.dto';
import { Client } from './entity/client.entity';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { ConflictException } from '@nestjs/common/exceptions';
@Injectable()
export class ClientService {

    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Client)
        private clientRepository : Repository<Client>
    ){}

    async inscrit(clientData: ClientInscritDto) : Promise<Partial<Client>>{
        const client = this.clientRepository.create({...clientData});
        client.salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
        client.mdp = await bcrypt.hash(clientData.mdp, client.salt);
        try{
            await this.clientRepository.save(client);
        }catch(err){
            throw new ConflictException(`le surname ${clientData.surname} ou l'email ${clientData.email} existe déjà`);
        }
        return client;
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your code for ClientModule.ts & Client.ts as well

Comment: @IstiyakTailor i forget to import typeOrmModule.forFeauture([Client]) ,, thaanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this was that I forget adding  in `client.module.ts` file:

```
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Client])
  ],
```